# How can I authenticate a user via api and session simultaneously using Guardian?

Tags: authentication, cookies, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to authenticate a user via api, but I'd also like to make sure they remain authenticated should they refresh the page.

Guardian.Plug.sign_in seems to fit the bill for storing user authentication in a cookie, but the cookie doesn't get set when I auth via my api.

This does work:

```
conn
|> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)
|> redirect(to: root_path(conn, :index))
```

Using these pipelines in this order:

```
  pipeline :browser do
     plug :accepts, ["html"]
     plug :fetch_session
     plug :fetch_flash
     plug :protect_from_forgery
     plug :put_secure_browser_headers
   end

   pipeline :browser_session do
     plug Guardian.Plug.VerifySession
     plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
   end
```

This does not:

```
conn
|> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user)
|> render("session.json")
```

Using these pipelines in this order:

```
  pipeline :api do
     plug :accepts, ["json"]
     plug Guardian.Plug.VerifyHeader
     plug Guardian.Plug.LoadResource
  end

  pipeline :api_session do
     plug :fetch_session
     plug :fetch_flash
     plug :put_secure_browser_headers
     plug Guardian.Plug.VerifySession
  end
```

I'm out of guesses as to why one works and the other doesn't as the behavior of [`redirect`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.1.4/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L298) and [`render`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.1.4/lib/phoenix/controller.ex#L479) seem to be essentially the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage your API and Browser using the same authentication then just go with the Browser authentication. For example, if your endpoint is a graphql middleware, then your NetworkLayer must be configured something like:

```
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
  new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql', {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
  })
);
```

That way your Relay app will use the same session as when you loaded/refreshed the page. This is the same as the old school Ajax stuff.

On the other hand, if all your front-end will be based on a Javascript client rendered in the browser (i.e.: React&Relay), then you can use your Phoenix controllers just to render the page were the Javascript will execute, and rely completely on JWT. For example, using **react-router**, you can do something like:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/session/new',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
    environment={Relay.Store}>
    <Route path="/" component={Hello}/>
    <Route path="/session/new" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} onEnter={requireAuth}>
      <IndexRoute component={HelloAdmin}/>
      <Route path="star-wars" component={StarWarsApp} queries={StarWarsQueries}/>
      <Route path="graphiql" component={GraphiQL} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('react-root')
);
```

Your auth will just check the existence of a JWT (maybe in localStorage). When you request your API, you'll have to send your JWT in the Authorization header. Again a Relay example:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
 new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer(GRAPHQL_URL, {
   headers: {
     Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
   }
 })
);
```

And then you'll be able to use Guardian stuff in the backend. Just remember that in this full API option, the logic to render your Login page will be fully implemented in the front-end.

Comment: Just a note: using localStorage for session tokens is a terrible idea due to XSS